# How to read and update the value inside an array using the edit-json-file npm

Tags: node.js, json, npm

Need to update the user.name and user.value.
JSON Format:

```
{
  "User": [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "value": 900000
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Add some code that you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this code below:

```js
const editJsonFile = require("edit-json-file");

let file = editJsonFile(`your-json.json`);

file.set("User", [
  {
    name: "yourname",
    value: 88
  }
]);

file.save();
```

Or the **second option**, you can do it like this code below:

```js
file.toObject().User[0] = {
  name: 'YourName',
  value: 1234
};

file.save();
```

For more, you can read the documentaion [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-json-file)

I hope it  can help you.